# Battling with my menu - Why is this broken ? - the <li> php is printed, not executed?

Tags: php, html, css

Im a little new to this, and this one issue is driving me mad..

The tag "?= $active[0] ?" on the

is getting printed rather than executed.

Any pointers appreciated...

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$active = 'class=""';

switch($url){

    case('/SSPCorporate/index.php'):
        $active[0] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/SSPCorporate/about.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/our-customers.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/our-partners.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/our-clients.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/our-standards.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/our-awards.php'):
        $active[1] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/SSPCorporate/solutions.php'):
        $active[2] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/SSPCorporate/services.php'):
        $active[3] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/SSPCorporate/sustainability.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/what-are-we-doing.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/what-can-you-do.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/what-we-support.php'):
    case('/SSPCorporate/references.php'):
        $active[4] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/SSPCorporate/healthcare.php'):
        $active[5] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/SSPCorporate/blog/'):
        $active[6] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/SSPCorporate/contact.php'):
        $active[7] = ' class="active"';
    break;

}
```

?>

```
echo($url);

?>

<nav>
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li id="first" <?= $active[0] ?> <a href="index.php" class="Bold">Home</a></li>
    <li <?= $active[1] ?> <a href="about.php" class="Bold">About</a></li>
    <li <?= $active[2] ?> <a href="solutions.php" class="Bold">Solutions</a></li>
    <li <?= $active[3] ?> <a href="services.php" class="Bold">Services</a></li>
    <li <?= $active[4] ?> <a href="sustainability.php" class="Bold">Sustainability</a></li>
    <li <?= $active[5] ?> <a href="healthcare.php" class="Bold">Healthcare</a></li>
    <li <?= $active[6] ?> <a href="/blog/" class="Bold">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="last" <?= $active[7] ?> <a href="contact.php" class="Bold">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The problem is the code is printing each letter from the string - not the string as a variable in the html..

<li c id="first"><a href="index.php" class="Bold">Home</a></li>

instead of 

<li class="active" id="first"><a href="index.php" class="Bold">Home</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely your server is not configured to support short tags `<? {code} ?>`. Try replacing them with `<?php {code} ?>`. You could also enable short tags, but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are PHP's `short_open_tag` directive is disabled.

That's actually a good thing as they lead to less portable code and shouldn't be used.

I would suggest using `<?php echo $active[0] ?>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP directive `short_open_tag`. If it probably off, which is the cause of the stuff beign not executed.

However, it's [no good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) to use them at all, and replacing with `<?php` would be better of a solution

Comment: Ok, great, fixed the short-tag syntax.

But now nothing is printed to the <li>... ?

Comment: Hmmm now what i thought was a variable is being split and printed as an array.. ?

Each letter of 'class=""' is being printed in each <li> .. have i defined $active wrongly ?

Comment: @swinhoe, try initializing `$active` like `$active = array();`

Comment: That just screwed the whole menu. Giving me an 'Undefined Offset' error. 

I dont think I want it as an array as what is currently being printed is one letter from the array string..

Any thoughts ?

Comment: @swinhoe, that's cause the array doesn't have every value, and you're requesting all of them. You do want it as an array, to work around the problem you can: 1) initialize it with empty strings 2) prepend calls to its members with `@` 3) store values instead of keys, for example, use `case ...: $array[] = 'about_buttons'` and then `<? if (in_array('about_buttons', $array)) echo 'class="active"' ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild stab,

```
<li <? echo $active[1]..
```

would work, as short tags are probably not enabled on your server's php configuration.